# How can I resolve this 500 error when sending JSON with Postman to MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, postman

I'm testing out a python scraper I've written that outputs JSON. Some of the variables in the JSON are going to be empty for the moment and will be manipulated later in a database. So, I need to declare them as null. But I'm getting an error when trying to put the JSON into Postman and sending it to the db.

What I'm doing is running my scraper, copying from its output a sample JSON object, pasting it into the body of a Postman post with Content-Type set to application/json, and sending it to a test database on Mongo.

Things I've tried and the results:

`variableName = ""`
`Error: 500 Internal Server Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

(My googling shows me this error means 'you are trying to use a null object as if it was a properly referenced object'.)

`variableName = null`
`Error: 500 Internal Server Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

`variableName = None`
Changing the value to None causes the JSON to output the word null and it then gives the same error as above.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please share your complete request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here turned out to be the format of the JSON itself. Mongo was expecting it in a very specific format, and it turned out there were a couple of differences. Adjusting those to match what we had told Mongo to expect fixed the problem.